# how to remove the gallery shortcode in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development

```
Your `warmHome_cutstr` function causes in the inline stylesheet of the gallery to be displayed. See gallery-post.jpg.[http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/4560/gallery-post.jpg][1] To solve this, you need to hook into the_content and remove the gallery shortcode. In functions.php:

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'warmHome_content_filter' );
    function warmHome_content_filter( $text )  {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        return $text;
    }
```

the following is my `warmHome_cutstr` function. how to correct it. i have added the above function. but don't know how to  remove the gallery shortcode.

```
function warmHome_cutstr($string, $length) {
             $string =strip_tags($string);
         $strcut= '';
         if(strlen($string) > $length) {
        preg_match_all("/[\x01-\x7f]|[\xc2-\xdf][\x80-\xbf]|\xe0[\xa0-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|[\xe1-\xef][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|\xf0[\x90-\xbf][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|[\xf1-\xf7][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]/", $string, $info);
         $j = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<count($info[0]); $i++) {

                $strcut .= $info[0][$i];

                $j = ord($info[0][$i]) > 127 ? $j + 2 : $j + 1;
                if ($j > $length - 3) {
                        return $strcut." ...";
                }
        }
        return join('', $info[0]);
                 } else {
                          return $string;
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the Gallery Short-code completely add this to your themes function.php file:

```
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the gallery shortcode in single php, here is the way to do it.
`if(has_shortcode(get_the_content(), 'gallery')){
       $pattern = get_shortcode_regex(); 
       echo  preg_replace("/$pattern/s", '', get_the_content());
    }?>`